# Composer cannot find the package for new require within Yii2 composer.json

Tags: php, github, yii, composer-php, yii2

Ok, I'm using `Yii2` and I am trying to add a new requirement/library to the project. Said library can be found here: https://github.com/cyphix333/SBBCodeParser

It is a forked project with an added `composer.json`.

I tried adding it as a requirement in the projects main composer file, ie:

```
"require": {
    //..........
    "samclarke/sbb-code-parser": "*"
},
```

Then I ran:

```
composer update
```

It just complained that it couldn't find the package or any version of it.

Then I removed that line and tried:

```
require samclarke/sbb-code-parser
```

I have the files already in my Yii `vendor` folder located at: `@app/vendor/samclarke/sbb-code-parser`

I'm pretty new to composer and am not sure what I'm doing wrong or how composer actually is supposed to know where to get the files from based on the package name.

Answer (score 0):

The package `samclarke/sbb-code-parser` can be found at Packagist.
https://packagist.org/packages/samclarke/sbb-code-parser

By default Composer tries to resolve a `stable`set of packages.
But this packages doesn't provide a stable version (version tag), yet - only the `dev-master` version exists. Composer can not resolve it.
In order to require it, you need to lower your minimum-stability for this package to development.

You might do this for one package explicitly:

```
"require": {
    "samclarke/sbb-code-parser": "dev-master@dev"
},
```

Or for all packages by setting:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

---

The package `cyphix333/SBBCodeParser` is not on Packagist.
It's a private fork. If you want exactly this code. You might add a `repositories` section to your `composer.json` and add repo with url and type with vcs there. Then Composer can load the package from the  VCS repository over at Github. This is described here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

That would work like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/cyphix333/SBBCodeParser"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "samclarke/sbb-code-parser": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the fork is also not well maintained and doesn't contain a valid `composer.json` file.

```
 [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
 No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/cyphix333/SBBCodeParser, could not load a package from it.
```

This needs to be fixed first....

Comment: Hi Jens...... thanks very much for the info. I wasn't aware it needed to be on packagist, though I *was* wondering how composer knew where to find the files. Yes, I wanted the code at github in the `cyphix333` fork, as I forked it as the other one as you said isn't maintained, so I updated it and created the composer file. But your statement above seems to state there isn't one in the `cyphix333` repo?

Comment: There is one, but it's not valid. Try to run `composer install -vvv` and you will see what Composer tries to fetch. The composer file is amongst these things, but needs some tweaking.. i'm not sure what it is, maybe it's the duplicate package name. Try'n'error: replace `samclarke/sbb-code-parser` with `cyphix333/SBBCodeParser` and commit, then try install again.

Comment: Do I run this `composer install -vvv` command within my main project dir or within the package dir that has the messed up composer file?

Comment: You run this in the directory of the main project. That's the project depending on the package.

Comment: Ok, I tried that with an update (set the repo to github as you advised above and changed the name of the repo in the composer file) and got this: `Skipped branch master, Package cyphix333/sbb-code-parser's source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., "reference": ...},
"https:\/\/github.com\/cyphix333\/SBBCodeParser\/tree\/master" given.`